# Is there a way to turn off the green light when calling or using the camera in Android 12?

Tags: android, security, camera, call, android-12

With the update to Android 12, a green icon and light appear when using the camera or making a call for security reasons.
Is there a way to turn off the green light when calling or using the camera in Android 12?

please help me

Answer (score 1):

adb shell cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default

LADB Utilities.  Only they will help.  And only for a day.  Then again enter the top two lines in the developer options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This feature was introduced for **security (privacy) reasons**. Rightly so. It should not be '**tampered**' with.
However, if there's a need to disable it for a compelling reason, then below is a possibility.

The **summary steps** are:

- install or have ADB (Android Debug Bridge) running on a computer (PC, laptop):
  NB: You do not need the full Android SDK or Android Studio. See more on [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)
- Enable `developer option` on the Android phone
- Connect the phone to the computer; typically, USB
- -- if connecting via WiFi, then enable wireless debugging, pair the phone to the computer and connect. Use appropriate ADB cmd on the computer
- -- `adb pair ipaddress:portnumber` , enter pair key displayed on phone
- -- `adb connect ipaddress:portnumber`
- enter the command to disable the green dot.
  `cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default`
- if you get an error ... `more than one devices connected`, then use
  `cmd -s ipaddress device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default`
  NB: To enable again,
  `cmd device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled true default`

For a lasting solution, kindly make use of the above within a Task; one can use Tasker
<sub>PS: I'm currently struggling using Tasker successfully for this. I'll update when successful</sub>

Answer (score 0):

no, there is no option, as you've noticed: its security reason. if any developer could do that (disable this warning) then why Android would introduce such feature... every developer with "not-friendly" intentions would do that in first lines of malicious software...

Answer (score 0):

If it is a system app:

```
import android.provider.DeviceConfig;
DeviceConfig.setProperty(DeviceConfig.NAMESPACE_PRIVACY,"camera_mic_icons_enabled","false",false);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**